# Validate if the input in the setter method is double or String

Tags: java

The value in the setter comes from a JTextFeild. I have try different method but it isn't working. I want to print out my custom error message. It isn't working for double, the String variable print the error message in the stacktrace.

This is the String method.

```
public void setInventoryname(String inventoryname) throws Exception {
        if(inventoryname.isEmpty()){
            throw new Exception ("Medicine name cannot be empty");
        }
        else{
        this.inventoryname = inventoryname;
    }
    }
```

result of the string method.

```
 java.lang.Exception: Medicine name cannot be empty
```

This is the double method

```
public void setInventorydesc(double inventorydesc) throws Exception {
      if(!Double.toString(inventorydesc).isEmpty()){

          throw new Exception("Set a number in Inventory qunatity");

      }
      else
      {
        this.inventoryqty = inventorydesc;

      } 
    }
```

The result of double

```
java.lang.NumberFormatException: For input string: "dfasdf"
```

I want to receive the same result as of string for double.

Answer (score 0):

Use Validator api and put your message.
Check org.apache.commons.validator

Comment: I checked it out. Didn't get a thing. Isn't there any simple solution, to fit in the if condition or something.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you should step back and ask yourself for a second: does that really make **sense**?

What I mean is: you have two different methods, that take completely different arguments; and that have completely semantics; and still you are asking that both give you the same error message?

Lets have a closer look. First of all, throwing **Exception** objects is really bad practice. If you want to use a checked exception, then you better create your own subclass and use that. If you prefer unchecked exceptions, then you could throw **IllegalArgumentException**.

And just for the record: when you receive a **double** argument, that thing is always a number. Somebody already took the incoming string and made it a number. So your method is absolutely pointless. In other words: besides the things I told you, you should have a look into the code **calling** your methods.

Finally: read java language style guides. You should use camelCase for your variable and method names. And there is absolutely no need to abbreviate, call the thing inventoryQuantity; then everybody knows what it is! And you know, it is **absolutely** wrong that a method called setInventory**Desc** changes the value of a field called inventory**Quantity**. This might sound like nitpicking, but be assured: being precise and disciplined is one of the core practices in programming!

Comment: Not the same error message, the message that gets thrown. the throw exception. I only need to compare the input of the argument whether it is String or not. Any alphabet must be deem as a invalid entry

Comment: I dont understand what you are saying. Again: the arguments of your two methods **already** have distinct types. One is a string, the other is primitive type double. A double is **never** a string. And you are asking to throw the **same** exception, with the **same** message for two **different** errors. That can't be correct!

Answer (score 0):

Double variable can never be empty, it can be zero.

You'll have to initialize the double variable, otherwise compiler will throw error.

If the zero value is what you mean by empty then you can compare that with zero to check.

You can not keep double variable uninitialized, it's all right with string but not with double.

Comment: The value in setter argument will come from a Jtextfeild. If a staff enter a String in the JtextFeild. I want to throw the custom error.

Comment: For that you can use Double.isNan(double d) method to verify if the value is numeric or not.Or try to type cast the the string to double if it goes into catch block then display error message to user

Answer (score 0):

Pass inventorydesc as a string first - and then work with it ...

```
   public void setInventorydesc(String inventorydesc) throws Exception {
          if(inventorydesc==null ||inventorydesc.isEmpty()){
              throw new Exception("Set a number in Inventory qunatity");
          }
          else
          {
            try{   
            this.inventoryqty = Double.parseDouble(inventorydesc);
            }catch (NumberFormatException e){
               throw new Exception("Inventory qunatity must be double");
            }

          } 
        }
```

Answer (score 0):

If the number comes from a text field first you must parse it to get the double.

```
public static void setInventorydesc(String inventorydesc) throws Exception {
    try{
        double convertedInventorydesc = Double.parseDouble(inventorydesc);
        this.inventoryqty = convertedInventorydesc;
    }
    catch (NumberFormatException ex){
        throw new Exception("Set a number in Inventory quantity",ex);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

try using this method

```
 Double.isNan(double d)
```

Use this method to verify if the value is numeric or not.Or try to type cast the the string to double if it goes into catch block then display error message to user